# "Verification expired" when anonymously running an SEDE query

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, error-message, captcha, anonymous-visitors

I ran a long SEDE query without logging in. Did the captcha, but after ~30 or ~60 sec got "Verification expired".

[image]

Unsure if bug or feature request. Saw it quite often over the past few months. Chrome+Win10.

Comment: Interesting there aren't any search results for this exact error message.

Comment: @bad_coder agreed, esp. since it's been around for a while

Comment: It's not a bug that the verification expires. When you click the checkbox, Google only considers the verification valid for 30-120 seconds, then forces you to revalidate. It might make sense to change the client-side scripting so that it removes the captcha box immediately when you click Run Query rather than after you get the results back, to avoid confusion for long-running queries. But I'm not familiar with how complicated that would be.

Comment: @animuson thanks, let's keep it as a feature request then.

Comment: I don’t think it’s new, I’ve seen it a lot - seems like several months at minimum.